# How to extract value from json object in SQL database using latest date?

Tags: sql, json, azure-sql-database

Inside my SQL table I have a field called series which is a json object of dates and values e.g. see below

| id | series |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6394317.0, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 6550781.0, "2016-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": 7107308.0} |
| 2 | {"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 106940.0, "2016-09-30T00:00:00.000Z": 110112.0} |

I would like to create a new column which extracts the  latest date value, so for example resulting in the following table

| id | series | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6394317.0, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 6550781.0, "2016-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": 7107308.0} | 7107308.0 |
| 2 | {"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 106940.0, "2016-09-30T00:00:00.000Z": 110112.0} | 110112.0 |

I have tried extracting all but no luck.

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL are very different DBMSs. Which of the two are you using?

Comment: it is Azure SQL database

Comment: This does not look like a very well organised JSON Document. You would have to know that date you want to pick out of the doc, unless you want to do quite a bit of text juggling (not what SQL is best at). I would suggest a complete redesign of this table and probably NOT using json at all

Comment: If only, but lets assume that the above isnt an option

Comment: I would be tempted to use something other than SQL, like read with PHP and do the string processing acrobatics there

Comment: That's useful to know. I'm not an SQL expert so if this seems like a particularly difficult task for SQL then I'll consider other tools. I wondered whether some SQL syntax like JSON_QUERY might have made it relatively easy

Comment: Would this be straightforward if I were wishing to always extract the final key in the json doc (each json doc being of different lengths).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below SQL query script to get the value of latest date.

**SQL script:**

```sql
select id,series,[value] from
(Select *,row_number() over (partition by a.id order by a.[key] desc) max_key from 
(select * from Json_tab t cross apply openjson(t. series))a)b where b.max_key=1
```

*Result:*

| id | series | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6394317.0, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 6550781.0, "2016-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": 7107308.0} | 7107308.0 |
| 2 | {"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 106940.0, "2016-09-30T00:00:00.000Z": 110112.0} | 110112.0 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k0rEgGA9)